# Understaing the Control Flow of if, else if, else in C

Tags: c, if-statement, control-flow

I have the following code in C. It is working, but I don't understand why it works. In my head it shouldn't. As you can see, I am working with two arrays, and I am 'grabbing' an element in the array with array[i] and array[j]. For array[j], I want to only test the first if and the second else if; for the array[i] I want to test only the second if, the second else if, and the last else.

The way this is written doesn't seem very elegant. What would be best practice in this case? Also, I though that C stopped testing conditions once an else if evaluated to True. If this is the case, why is the code still working when it evaluates the first else if as true; it seems to continue testing with the array[i]. (This is how I want it to work; I just don't know why it works).

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= numChars; ++i )
{   
    int index = j % keyNumChars; 

    if (isupper(argv[1][index]))
    {
        // execute code A1
    }

    else if (islower(argv[1][index]))
    {
        // execute code A2
    }

    if (isupper(plainText[i]))
    {
        // execute code B1
    }

    else if (islower(plainText[i]))
    {
        // execute code B2
    }

    else
    {
        //execute code B3
    }
}
```

Comment: It continues because you have two distinct blocks - you have an if statement after an else statement, so regardless of the result of the else it will continue with the next if.  Your second block will only match one if-elseif-else

Comment: Looks fine on first sight. You are not confusing this with shortcuts in logical expressions?

Answer (score 1):

The first `else` goes with the first `if`, and both of those have to do with tests of j.  Once those are done, the path of execution then starts over with the second `if`, since it has no `else` in front of it; the second `if`, `else if`, and `else` go together, and have to do with tests of i.  That should explain why both the i tests and the j tests are working.

Incidentally, the code probably needs to increment j at some point; otherwise it just keeps testing j=0 each time through.

Comment: Thank you. It does increment J every time the second if or the second else if is true, but not the else. Should first else if be changed to an else then?

Comment: @user3237895: no because all of the branches are in the same loop, and there's no code posted here that increments `j`, only `i` is incremented. And no `i` won't be incremented any more than usual (ie once for each time the loop body is executed)

Comment: Sorry. Within B1 and B2, there is a ++j in each of those blocks

Comment: @user3237895: awkward place for them, but provided you don't end up in the B3 block, then `j` will be incremented. Add a `++j` _outside_ of all the branches, or add one to the B3 block, and j will be incremented on each iteration...

Comment: @user3237895 if one of either isUpper or isLower is always true, you could change the first "else if" to "else".  If there's a possibility that neither might be true, the change is probably a bad idea.  If the current code works as desired, though, my inclination is always to leave it alone - "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: The reason they are outside is that is that if array[i] is not a letter, i want to re use array[j] for the next array[i+1]. I cant increment it each time

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to reformat

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= numChars; ++i )
{   
    int index = j % keyNumChars; 

    if (isupper(argv[1][index])) {
        // execute code A1
    } else if (islower(argv[1][index])) {
        // execute code A2
    }

    if (isupper(plainText[i])) {
        // execute code B1
    } else if (islower(plainText[i])) {
        // execute code B2
    } else {
        //execute code B3
    }
}
```

Comment: This does help thank you! So whenever you start an if, it is treated independently of anything above...

Comment: The top level if statements are independent. The inner if is only evaluated if the outer if failed in the above construction, so we land in the outer else branch where we hit the inner if etc. Maybe this helps http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp1/node99.html