# How does the else-if works in C?

Tags: c

I'm learning C. and wrote this program to print the words in the input line by line. When I use "{}" in the first "if", the program works correctly but without them
(like this):

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') 
            if (state == IN) {
                putchar('\n');
                state = OUT;
            }
```

, it doesn't. What is the reason for this?

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int c, state;
    state = OUT;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
            if (state == IN) {
                putchar('\n');
                state = OUT;
            }
        }

        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
        }

        if (state == IN)
            putchar(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As best practice, always use `{}` in `if` statements. They define a block of code to be executed upon a true statement. If you don't use them, only the next command will be executed upon a true statement.

Comment: in `if (cond1) { if (cond2) { stuff } } else { ... }` the else applies to *cond1* ... in `if (cond1) if (cond2) { stuff } else { ... }` the else applies to *cond2* ...

Comment: with brackets the else goes with the first if, withou it goes with the second if

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understaing the Control Flow of if, else if, else in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022726/understaing-the-control-flow-of-if-else-if-else-in-c)

Comment: You've encountered the [Dangling Else problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that C does not care about indentation.

This fragment:

```
    if (condition1)
        if (condition2)
            statement2;
    else
        statement3;
```

has misleading indentation. It ought to be indented as follows:

```
    if (condition1)
        if (condition2)
            statement2;
        else
            statement3;
```

and is equivalent to:

```
   if (condition1) {
       if (condition2) {
           statement2;
       } else {
           statement3;
       }
   }
```

But the indentation of the original code suggests that the programmer actually wanted the following:

```
    if (condition1) {
        if (condition2) {
            statement2;
        }
    } else {
        statement3;
    }
```

I think it is a good idea to *always* use braces unless you need to follow a misguided coding style requirement that says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, you're asking why without `{}` your `if` isn't executed well. If that's the case, then the reason is that without `{}`, only the next command will be executed when the condition is true. In your case, it would mean that the `else if` would apply for the `if (state == IN)` line and not the intended `if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if(x)
    if(y) {
        // Code
    }
else {
    // Code
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(x) {
    if(y) {
        // Code
    } else {
    // Code
    }
}
```

and not

```
if(x) {
    if(y) {
        // Code
    } 
} else {
    // Code
}
```

I sometimes omit the braces for single statements. Some people think it's a bad practice, but coders does not have a universal agreement on this point. However, if the single statement is `if`, `switch`, `while`, `for` or `do`, then I NEVER omit the braces. Like this:

```
if(x) {
    while(y) {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) // Optional to put braces here
            A[i]+=42;
    }
}
```

The braces for `if` and `while` is mandatory (in the sense that I consider it very bad practice to omit them) here but the omitted braces for the `for` loop is more of a personal preference, and in either case, no matter how bad you consider this to be, it's definitely WAY WORSE to omit them for the others.

Another thing is that if you have `if-else` then I use braces on both or none. Like this:

```
if(x) {
     // Single statement, but since the else branch has braces, I have them here too
     puts("Hello"); 
} else {
     puts("Error");
     exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if, without the {} it takes the first line only.

if, with the {} takes all the statement within the braces as a body of the content and execute it

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement without an `else` controls exactly one statement. In this example, only `statement0` is controlled by the `if`:

```
if (test)
    statement0;  // Controlled by the "if".
statement9;      // Not controlled by the "if".
```

To control more than one statement with an `if`, C has a *compound statement* that forms multiple statements into one compound statement:

```
{
    statement0;
    statement1;
    statement2;
    …
}
```

Then we can use a compound statement as the single statement controlled by an `if`:

```
if (test)
{
    statement0;  // Controlled by the "if".
    statement1;  // Controlled by the "if".
    statement2;  // Controlled by the "if".
    …            // Controlled by the "if".
}
statement9;      // Not controlled by the "if".
```

With an `else`, an `if … else` statement controls two statements, selecting one or the other:

```
if (test)
    statement0;  // Controlled, executed if test is true.
else
    statement1;  // Controlled, executed if test is false.
statement9;      // Not controlled.
```

As with a plain `if` statement, each controlled statement can be a compound statement.

There is no `else if` in C, but a statement controlled by an `if … else` can be another `if` statement:

```
if (test)
    statement0;
else
    if (another test)
        statement1;
```

People sometimes write this with the `else` and the `if` on the same line, but the compiler still interprets it as illustrated above:

```
if (test)
    statement0;
else if (another test)
    statement1;
```

It does make sense to write multiple `else if` cases like this because it gives organization to selecting one of several mutually exclusive cases:

```
if (test0)
    statement0;
else if (test1)
    statement1;
else if (test2)
    statement2;
else
    statement3;
```

The above code will executed **exactly one** of `statement0`, `statement1`, `statement2`, or `statement3`. It will execute the **first** one for which its associated test is true, or, if none are true, the final statement, `statement3`, since it does not have an `if`. Again, note this statement structure is not a new type of C statement; it is a use of the previously defined `if … else` statement.

In contrast, this code will execute **each** statement for which its associated test is true, so it may execute multiple of the statements:

```
if (test0)
    statement0;
if (test1)
    statement1;
if (test2)
    statement2;
```